# Why use [i:i+1] instead of just [i]?

Tags: python

Why can't we use `[i]` instead of `[i:i+1]` in here? (line 10).
Just for context: This code is part of a solution to the problem described here: https://www.codewars.com/kata/57814d79a56c88e3e0000786/train/python
But it's more a general question! I used just `[i]` in a similiar solution of mine but it got me an index error.

```
def decrypt(text, n):
    if text in ("", None):
        return text

    ndx = len(text) // 2

    for i in range(n):
        a = text[:ndx]
        b = text[ndx:]
        text = "".join(b[i:i+1] + a[i:i+1] for i in range(ndx + 1))
    return text



def encrypt(text, n):
    for i in range(n):
        text = text[1::2] + text[::2]
    return text
```

Comment: `[i]` gives you the element or an IndexError, `[i:i+1]` gives you a list containing the element or an empty list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `list[i]` will yield an element, using `list[i:i+1]` will yield a list with one element. Since `join` expects a list as argument, using the former will error on you while using the latter works as expected

```py
lst = [1,2,3]

lst[1]
2

lst[1:2]
[2]
```